# Escuchar el teclado de Android para detectar cuando se escribe una palabra concreta

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

Me gustaría poder obtener las teclas que va pulsando el usuario dentro de una activity para saber cuando ha escrito una palabra concreta en el teclado de Android. Hasta el momento he utilizado el método onKeyDown sin mucho éxito:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    String key = KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode);
    word = word + key;
    Log.d("palabra",word);

    if (word.compareTo(coincidencia)){
        //Hacer algo cuando la palabra introducida coincida con la que espero
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Con este código no llega a mostrarme nada en el Log, por lo que no llego a comprender como funciona realmente éste método.

Necesito que esto funcione siempre que se introduzca algo en el teclado, así que no me valdría comparar con lo que el usuario pueda introducir en un input por ejemplo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes mejor agregar un textListener a ti EditText

Comment: @MiguelOsorio Al final de la pregunta he explicado que no me valdría controlar sólo lo que se introduzca en un input concreto, si no controlar el teclado de toda la activity, ya que esta va a tener una webview donde también debe escuchar las teclas presionadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta utilizar "dispatchKeyEvent"

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
String key = KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode);
word = word + key;
Log.d("palabra",word);

if (word.compareTo(coincidencia)){
    //Hacer algo cuando la palabra introducida coincida con la que espero
}
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```